# why I get illegal hardware instruction message from a simple code?

Tags: c, string, header-files, hardware, illegal-instruction

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char s1[] = "harry";
    char s2[] = "ravi";
    char s3[54];

    puts(strcat(s1, s2));
    
    strcpy(s3 ,strcat(s1, s2));
    puts(s3);
    
    return 0;
}
```

this is the error that I will get

```
cd "/Users/deepkar/Desktop/C_COURSE/" && gcc tut27.c -o tut27 && "/Users/deepkar/Desktop/C_COURSE/"tut27
deepkar@Deeps-Air C_COURSE % cd "/Users/deepkar/Desktop/C_COURSE/" && gcc tut27.c -o tut27 && "/Users/deepkar/Desktop/C_COURSE/"tut27
zsh: illegal hardware instruction  "/Users/deepkar/Desktop/C_COURSE/"tut27
deepkar@Deeps-Air C_COURSE %
```

Comment: `s1` doesn't have room for the combined string. The behavior is undefined.

Comment: The [`strcat`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat) function doesn't create a new string. It appends the second string to the first string. The first string *must* have space enough for the combined strings, including null-terminator.

Comment: See this string handling FAQ here: [Common string handling pitfalls in C programming](https://software.codidact.com/posts/284849)

Answer (score 0):

The problem come from your code having undefined behavior:

You call `strcat(s1, s2);` twice, attempting to copy the characters from `s2` at the end of the array pointed to by `s1`, but `s1` already contains a string `"harry"` that along with its null terminator fills the array completely, the definition `char s1[] = "harry";` giving it a length of 6 bytes.  `strcat` writes beyond the end of the array `s1`, overwriting important data, such as the return address for function `main`. The observed behavior is consistent with the CPU branching to an invalid address.

You can copy `s1` to `s3` and catenate `s2` to that instead.